# Which events can be bound to a Tkinter Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a small application with Tkinter. I would like to clean few things in a function called when my window is closed. I am trying to bind the *close event* of my window with that function. I don't know if it is possible and what is the corresponding sequence.

The Python documentation says: `See the bind man page and page 201 of John Ousterhout’s book for details`.

Unfortunately, I don't have these resources in my hands. Does anybody know the list of events that can be bound?

An alternative solution would be to clean everything in the `__del__` of my Frame class. For an unknown reason it seems that it is never called. Does anybody knows what can be the cause? Some circular dependencies?

As soon as, I add a control (uncomment in the code below), the `__del__` is not called anymore. Any solution for that problem?

```
from tkinter import *

class MyDialog(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Test")

        Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.list = Listbox(self, selectmode=BROWSE)
        self.list.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    def __del__(self):
        print("bye-bye")

dialog = MyDialog()
dialog.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm) is the bind man page you may have been looking for; I believe the event you're trying to bind is `Destroy`. `__del__` is not to be relied on (just too hard to know when a circular reference loop, e.g. parent to child widget and back, will stop it from triggering!), using event binding is definitely preferable.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much. I agree that the circular reference is a nigthmare.

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if the link to the man page wasn't to a personal account at princeton. There's an official set of man pages at tcl.tk/man.

Answer (score 3):

A more-or-less definitive resource for events is the [bind man page for Tk](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm).  I'm not exactly clear what you're wanting to do, but binding on `"<Destroy>"` is probably the event you are looking for. Whether it does what you really need, I don't know.

```
 ...
 self.bind("<Destroy>", self.callback)
 ...
 def callback(self, event):
     print("callback called")
```

Comment: Thnaks for the answer and the link. Unfortunately, I just can choose only correct answer. But I've upvoted :-)